# How does the data in this unusual URL work?

Tags: url

how does this URL work?

```
http://help.mysupermarket.co.uk/index.php/faq/mysupermarket-service-centre/
```

There is no `?key1=value1&key2=value2`, after `index.php` but instead another directory path.

Comment: Typically *URL Rewriting*: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php